# Error in databrick - Column is not iterable

Tags: pyspark

```py
dim_processo.withColumn(
    col("Cliente"),
    when(
        dim_processo.Cliente.endswith('"parque",lda.'),
        regexp_replace(
            dim_processo.Cliente, 'Restaurante "parque",lda.', "Restaurante parque,lda."
        ),
    ),
)
```

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

Help???

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of `withColumn` should be the column name (a string)
here is the fix :

```
withColumn(
    "Cliente"
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.